# 3x3 Grid Acting Strange at Certain Widths

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a responsive 3x3 grid of video thumbnails that use pretty photo to lightbox vimeo clips.  It works great at some resolutions, but as you resize the width of the browser window, it rapidly changes from 3x3 to this nonsense.
[image: What?]

This is the offending CSS.

```
     .thumb
{
float: right;
width: 25%;
height: auto;
margin: 2%;
}
    .maincontent
{
margin:0 auto;
width:90%;
float:right;
}
```

And a snippet of the HTML if that matters.

```
        <div class="maincontent">
    <a href="http://vimeo.com/428525" rel="prettyPhoto" title="">
       <img class="thumb" src="http://ftfrmedia.com/images/thumbnails/Overview-thumb.jpg" alt="Company Overview" width="60" />
       </a>
```

I'm seriously stumped...

Comment: Probably gonna need more of that HTML and CSS. Perhaps a link to the misbehaving page?

Comment: http://forestfloormedia.com/work/  Have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a problem with floats in `.thumb` and `img`.

Replacing the floats with `display: inline-block` should resolve the issue:

```
.thumb {
    height: auto;
    margin: 2em;
    width: 25%;
}

img {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;        /* IE7 hack as it does not */
    *zoom: 1;                /* support display: inline-block */  
    height: 3em;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    margin-top: -1.6em;
    width: 3em;
}
```

**Update**

As pointed out by **@DaveHaigh** below, there is no need to use `display: inline-block` on the img element as this already accepts a height and width property.

Therefore, just removing the floats will fix this problem. If you would like to keep the right to left flow of the images then you can add `direction: rtl` to their parent:

```
.maincontent {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

The downside to this would be that it would also flow any text right to left, but this does not appear to be a problem in your website as you are not using any text within the `.maincontent` element.

Comment: That, with some tweeks, worked.  Thank you.  But it, unsurprisingly, no longer is on the right side. Whats the best way to put it back without breaking things again?

Comment: why do you need to add `display: inline-block` to the images?

Comment: @MobyD You could either re-arrange your pictures or you can add `direction: rtl;` to `.maincontent` - but this would cause any written text to flow right to left as well

Comment: I thought that image elements were `inline-block` by default therefore setting this is redundant.

Comment: @MobyD I have added one solution to positioning your maincontent container back to the right as a comment to my own answer.

Comment: @DaveHaigh you are indeed correct - the `inline-block` is not needed on the image

Comment: You were actually both right in a couple regards.  The float from the img (which I was using to affect the logo due to laziness) needed to be separated by moving those CSS properties to #logo.  I then replicated the float by adding margins to the .thumbs for now

Answer (score 1):

remove the floats on the `.thumb` and `img`. And also replace the `margin: 2em;` on `.thumb` with a percent value e.g. `2%`.

Comment: to position the container back to the right you could remove the `float: right` from `.maincintent` and add a left margin to it e.g. `margin:0 0 0 20%;`